# Is lock required for single writer situation?

Tags: c#, dictionary, locking, .net-core

I'm using .netcore with C#, I have a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<>` that is shared and been access by multiple tasks, but there is only one task that is writing to and updating the key value pairs, and all other tasks(more than one) are only reading from the dictionary. In this situation, do I need to use a lock to protect it, in terms of thread safety?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  `Dictionary` cannot be safely read from while a write is in process; the internal data storage is not in a valid state, and so exceptions or nonsensical results can arise.

Comment: Ok, to solve this, is lock or concurrentditionary a better choice?

Comment: @fluter That's up to you to decide.  Both can solve this problem, if used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.